# replacing columns values to missing to specific rows/IDs in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to replace columns x1 and x2 to NA but specifically for id 1 and 2.

```
id<-c(1,2,3)
x1<-c("f", "g", "h")
x2<-c(100, 200, 300)

data<-data.frame(cbind(id,x1,x2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do -

```
cols <- c('x1', 'x2')
ids <- c(1, 2)
data[data$id %in% ids, cols] <- NA
data

#  id   x1  x2
#1  1 <NA>  NA
#2  2 <NA>  NA
#3  3    h 300
```

Comment: what about in a situation where the variables are so many hence cumbersome to list the var names?

Comment: So how do you know which variables you want to turn to `NA` ?

Comment: using a particular pattern such as starts_with()

Comment: You can use `grep` i.e `cols <- grep('^x', names(data))` so that you don't have to list each column name.